# Deploying an app in private beta without any coding

Tags: grails, heroku, cloudflare

I'm working on a Grails 2.0 app, deploying it on Heroku, with a launchpage on kickofflabs and a DNS on CloudFlare. I'm looking for a simple way to password-protect my app in private beta and give access to it only to a few selected people, all that without adding any code to my app.

Back when I used Cloudbees, it had a nice private mode to do just that. But I couldn't find any equivalent in Heroku, either natively or using an add-on. I also had a look at CloudFlare apps but no success there either.

Does anyone know any simple way to do that? It seems generic enough to me.

Comment: Because the Heroku http router / load balancer just passes requests through, there isn't an interceptor point in the Cedar stack that would allow for this.  So the logic will have to go in your app.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Invitation Only plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/invitation-only)

Never used it myself though...

And not sure if it needs updating for 2.0 :-/

And I guess this needs some coding...  So this answer basically doesn't answer your question...  Sorry about that...

Comment: The problem with the invitation only plugin is that it limits access to certain parts of the site. What I want is to limit access to the entire site so the interception needs to happen before reaching the app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not front it with Apache and use mod_jk to connect to your Tomcat with the Grails application. This way you can have .htaccess do the access control?